# Cannot upload file to my Ubuntu server through php script

Tags: php, ubuntu, file-upload, server, permissions

My problem is setting permission to var/www which seems impossible to me.so this is a problem related to ubuntu because i found many other people facing the same problem in ubuntu.

Here is my script

```
<?php 
ini_set("display_errors","on");
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    echo "submitted<br>";
    $file_name     = $_POST['fname'];
    $uploader_name = $_POST['uname'];

    if(!empty($_POST['description'])){
        $description   =  $_POST['description'];
    }
    else{
        $description="";
    }

    if(isset($_FILES['upload'])){
        echo 'success';
        move_uploaded_file($_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'], "security/{$_FILES['upload']['name']}");  
    }
    else
    {
        echo 'file not uploaded';
    }
}


 ?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>upload</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action='upload.php' method='post'>
    <strong style="color:red;display: inline-block;width: 180px">Name of File:*</strong>
    <input type="text" name="fname" size="50"  maxlength="100" required=""><br><br>

    <strong style="color:red;display: inline-block;width: 180px">Name of Uploader:*</strong>
    <input type="text" name="uname" size='50' maxlength="100" required=""><br><br>

    <strong style="color:red;display: inline-block;width: 180px ">Description(optional)</strong><br><br>
    <textarea rows="20" cols="100"></textarea><br><br>

    <input type="file" name="upload"  required=""><br><br>
    <input type="submit" name="submit"  value="Upload">

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried everything I found on Ask Ubuntu, Stack Overflow and Ubuntu Forums ie chmod and chown.

PS:this question was moved from askubuntu.Please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to add `enctype = "multipart/form-data"` to your form

Try it as

```
<form action='upload.php' method='post' enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Comment: Thank you sir.I was driving myself crazy.i thought it was something with the permission

Comment: Welcome Please mark it as answer by clicking the tick... : )

Answer (score 0):

To upload a file you have to give `enctype='multipart/form-data` to form. change your form to

```
<form action='upload.php' method='post' enctype='multipart/form-data>
```